# Python - capture Popen stdout AND display on console?

Tags: python, pipe, popen

I want to capture stdout from a long-ish running process started via `subprocess.Popen(...)` so I'm using `stdout=PIPE` as an arg.

However, because it's a long running process I also want to send the output to the console (as if I hadn't piped it) to give the user of the script an idea that it's still working.

Is this at all possible?

Cheers.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874815/how-do-i-get-real-time-information-back-from-a-subprocess-popen-in-python-2-5

Comment: related: [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you simply `print` it as you read it from the pipe?

Comment: Ah! (light bulb moment!) - p.stdout is a file like object. So I just need to call readline() on it in a loop? Right? What's the best way to exit the loop - when p.stdout returns empty string? Should I still do p.wait() after just to be sure?

Comment: @Steve: An empty string returned from reading p.stdout means that the child has closed its stdout, but not necessarily that it's terminated.  p.wait() will wait for it to terminate.

Answer (score 5):

The buffering your long-running sub-process is probably performing will make your console output jerky and very bad UX. I suggest you consider instead using [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) (or, on Windows, [wexpect](http://code.google.com/p/wexpect/)) to defeat such buffering and get smooth, regular output from the sub-process. For example (on just about any unix-y system, after installing pexpect):

```
>>> import pexpect
>>> child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "echo ba; sleep 1; echo bu"', logfile=sys.stdout); x=child.expect(pexpect.EOF); child.close()
ba
bu
>>> child.before
'ba\r\nbu\r\n'
```

The ba and bu will come with the proper timing (about a second between them). Note the output is not subject to normal terminal processing, so the carriage returns are left in there -- you'll need to post-process the string yourself (just a simple `.replace`!-) if you need `\n` as end-of-line markers (the lack of processing is important just in case the sub-process is writing binary data to its stdout -- this ensures all the data's left intact!-).

Answer (score 2):

S. Lott's comment points to [Getting realtime output using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess) and [Real-time intercepting of stdout from another process in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085071/real-time-intercepting-of-stdout-from-another-process-in-python)

I'm curious that Alex's answer here is different from his answer 1085071.
My simple little experiments with the answers in the two other referenced questions has given good results...

I went and looked at wexpect as per Alex's answer above, but I have to say reading the comments in the code I was not left a very good feeling about using it.

I guess the meta-question here is when will pexpect/wexpect be one of the Included Batteries?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can pipe your process into tee and capture only one of the streams.
Something along the lines of `sh -c 'process interesting stuff' | tee /dev/stderr`.

Of course, this only works on Unix-like systems.

Comment: Unfortunately still subject to buffering-caused jerkiness:-(.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by pty.openpty() suggestion somewhere above, tested on python2.6, linux. Publishing since it took a while to make this working properly, w/o buffering...

```
def call_and_peek_output(cmd, shell=False):
    import pty, subprocess
    master, slave = pty.openpty()
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=shell, stdin=None, stdout=slave, close_fds=True)
    os.close(slave)
    line = ""
    while True:
        try:
            ch = os.read(master, 1)
        except OSError:
            # We get this exception when the spawn process closes all references to the
            # pty descriptor which we passed him to use for stdout
            # (typically when it and its childs exit)
            break
        line += ch
        sys.stdout.write(ch)
        if ch == '\n':
            yield line
            line = ""
    if line:
        yield line

    ret = p.wait()
    if ret:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(ret, cmd)

for l in call_and_peek_output("ls /", shell=True):
    pass
```