# Python capture output from wget?

Tags: python

Is it possible to capture output from wget and other command line programs that use curses?
Here is what I have right now:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
for line in p.stdout:
    print "a"
```

This works fine for programs that have simple output, but not for wget and other programs that use curses.

Comment: I don't think wget uses curses. It just prints its messages to stderr rather than stdout.

Comment: For the case of wget it's probably stderr that you need to intercept (see http://blog.doughellmann.com/2007/07/pymotw-subprocess.html for some examples) For the intercepting the curses programs - I suspect that would become tedious very quickly when you need to emulate the terminal...

Comment: My bad, I thought that to update an existing line you had to use curses.

Comment: A common means of printing progress bars and spinners in terminal applications is to use the backspace/rubout character.  It's best to check that your file descriptor is connected to a terminal (avoid cluttering regular files with ASCII control characters).  However, this doesn't require curses.  In fact the Python termios module has just what you need for this sort of thing.  (Usually, even without the termios module you can sys.stdout.write(chr(0x08)) to backspace over a character on the current line).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe that `wget` is using curses.

Normally when I want to use `wget` in a script I'd use the **`-O -`** option to force its output to *stdout*.  I suspect you're trying to capture the text that you **normally** see on your console when you're running it, which would be ***stderr***.

From the command line, outside of Python, just run a command like:

```
wget -O - http://www.somesite.org/ > /tmp/wget.out 2> /tmp/wget.err
```

Then look at the two output files.  If you see any output from `wget` on your console/terminal then you are running some different flavor of the command than I've seen.

If, as I suspect, you're actually interested in the *stderr* messages then you have two choices.

- Change your command to add 2>&1 and add `shell=True` to your `Popen()` arguments
- Alternatively (and preferably) add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to your `Popen()` arguments

The former is handy if you weren't using *stdout* anyway (assuming your using
`wget` to fetch the data and write it into files).  In the latter case you read from the *stderr* file option to get your data.

BTW: if you really did need to capture **curses** data ... you could try to use the standard ***pty*** module but I wouldn't recommend that.  You'd be far better off fetching the **`pexpect`** module from:

- [PyPI: pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/4.2.1):

And don't be scared off by the age or version numbering, it works on Python 2.5 and 2.6 as well as 2.4 and 2.3.

Comment: Definitely with pexpect, as I recommended in other recent answers -- e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283061

Comment: Why would I add shell=True? It is not handy at all - and needlessy invokes a new shell process.

Comment: I was pointing out that for redirections of the 2>&1 sort you'd either have to do shell=True or you'd have to do your own os.fork(), os.dup2() and os.execve() functions.

Comment: You should be getting wget's output before it's "done" (that is before the process has completed).  However, it's likely that you're seeing some buffering effects.  Try setting the bufsize=0 on the subprocess list.

Comment: @Jim Dennis: you're wrong.  subprocess.Popen can do `2>&1` just fine, you don't need to fork anything and it works in all platforms. Just use `subproces.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: @nosklo I was referring to the literal syntax 2>&1 as part of the cmd string.  Of course there are other ways to get this effect by manipulating the file descriptors (as I said in my original response).