# How to implement full wget command into python

Tags: python, web-crawler, wget

Is there a way you can use a full wget command into python?

I know that we can do this: `os.system('wget %s' %%url)`

But I want a full command with all of the data saved into a directory: 
`wget -r --accept "*.exe,*.dll,*.zip,*.msi,*.rar,*.iso" ftp://ftp.apple.asimov.com/ -P e:\e`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. You know how to pass one argument to `wget` but you don't know how to pass six?

Comment: `os.system` takes a string as an argument. You can build up the rest of the string using normal string methods just as you can with `'wget ' + url`.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `subprocess` module for that (this is what `os.system` calls but with a bit more flexibility). Specifically, you can use the `call` function in the following way to execute any command

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(r'wget -r --accept "*.exe,*.dll,*.zip,*.msi,*.rar,*.iso" ftp://ftp.apple.asimov.com/ -P e:\e', shell=True)
```

Alternatively, you can pass individual arguments as a list omitting the shell flag:

```
 subprocess.call(['wget', '-r', ...])
```

Also check the return value for errors. For details, see the [standard library documentation on subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Is there a way to impalement a progress bar? That shows the downloading process?

Comment: Sure, since wget can do this you just need to pipe its output to the console. Look at the stdout parameter of the call function.

Comment: Just piping the stderr/stdout of a command like wget probably isn't going to work well. You'll get better results by using the pexpect/wexpect module. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1283066/2073595

Comment: looking at the wexpect the code would be:  `child = wexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "echo ba; sleep 1; echo bu"', logfile=sys.stdout); x=child.expect(wexpect.EOF); child.close()` How would I go about implementing the wget code from above into it?

Comment: Well, you copy and paste the wget command into the spawn call. What is not clear about that?

Comment: `child = wexpect.spawn('wget -r --accept "*.exe,*.dll,*.zip,*.msi,*.rar,*.iso" ftp://ftp.bartylak.com/ -P e:\e', shell=True, '/bin/bash -c "echo ba; sleep 1; echo bu"', logfile=sys.stdout); x=child.expect(wexpect.EOF); child.close()` This gives me an error, I have tried researching but couldnt find any information.

Comment: No, like this: `wexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "<your wget call goes in here>"', ...)`

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but im still getting errors `child = wexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "wget -r --accept "*.exe,*.dll,*.zip,*.msi,*.rar,*.iso" ftp://ftp.bartylak.com/ -P e:\e"', "echo ba; sleep 1; echo bu", logfile=sys.stdout);
x=child.expect(wexpect.EOF); 
child.before
child.close()'