# catching stdout in realtime from subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I want to `subprocess.Popen()` rsync.exe in Windows, and print the stdout in Python.

My code works, but it doesn't catch the progress until a file transfer is done! I want to print the progress for each file in real time.

Using Python 3.1 now since I heard it should be better at handling IO.

```
import subprocess, time, os, sys

cmd = "rsync.exe -vaz -P source/ dest/"
p, line = True, 'start'


p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     shell=True,
                     bufsize=64,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in p.stdout:
    print(">>> " + str(line.rstrip()))
    p.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085071/real-time-intercepting-of-stdout-from-another-process-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874815/how-do-i-get-real-time-information-back-from-a-subprocess-popen-in-python-2-5, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527197/intercepting-stdout-of-a-subprocess-while-it-is-running

Comment: (Coming from google?) all PIPEs will deadlock when one of the PIPEs' buffer gets filled up and not read. e.g. stdout deadlock when stderr is filled. Never pass a PIPE you don't intend read.

Comment: Could someone explain why you couldn't just set stdout to sys.stdout instead of subprocess.PIPE?

Comment: @Mike, because the topic is about capturing. If printing the child's output to the parent's is the goal, we can simply leave the stdout argument unset. Because the child's stdout inherits parent's by default.

Answer (score 125):

Some rules of thumb for `subprocess`.

- **Never** use `shell=True`. It needlessly invokes an extra shell process to call your program.
- When calling processes, arguments are passed around as lists. `sys.argv` in python is a list, and so is `argv` in C. So you pass a **list** to `Popen` to call subprocesses, not a string.
- Don't redirect `stderr` to a `PIPE` when you're not reading it.
- Don't redirect `stdin` when you're not writing to it.

Example:

```
import subprocess, time, os, sys
cmd = ["rsync.exe", "-vaz", "-P", "source/" ,"dest/"]

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(">>> " + line.rstrip())
```

That said, it is probable that rsync buffers its output when it detects that it is connected to a pipe instead of a terminal. This is the default behavior - when connected to a pipe, programs must explicitly flush stdout for realtime results, otherwise standard C library will buffer.

To test for that, try running this instead:

```
cmd = [sys.executable, 'test_out.py']
```

and create a `test_out.py` file with the contents:

```
import sys
import time
print ("Hello")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(10)
print ("World")
```

Executing that subprocess should give you "Hello" and wait 10 seconds before giving "World". If that happens with the python code above and not with `rsync`, that means `rsync` itself is buffering output, so you are out of luck.

A solution would be to connect direct to a `pty`, using something like `pexpect`.

Comment: `shell=False` is right thing when you construct command line especially from user entered data. But nevertheless `shell=True` is useful too when you get the whole command line from trusted source (e.g. hardcoded in the script).

Comment: @Denis Otkidach: I don't think that warrants usage of `shell=True`. Think about it - you're invoking another process on your OS, involving memory allocation, disk usage, processor scheduling, just to **split a string**! And one you joined yourself!! You could split in python, but it is easier writing each parameter separately anyway. Also, using a list means you don't have to escape special shell chars: spaces, `;`, `>`, `<`, `&`.. Your parameters can contain those chars and you don't have to worry! I can't see a reason to use `shell=True`, really, unless you're running a shell-only command.

Comment: nosklo,that should be:

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

Comment: shell=False is bad but it allows convenient ways to pipe. Is there a nice way to run a string of pipes?

i.e. run the command 

'cat longfile.tab | cut -f1 | head -100'.split()

Comment: @mathtick: I'm not sure why you would do those operations as separate processes... you can cut file contents and extract first field easily in python by using the `csv` module. But as an example, your pipeline in python would be: `p = Popen(['cut', '-f1'], stdin=open('longfile.tab'), stdout=PIPE) ; p2 = Popen(['head', '-100'], stdin=p.stdout, stdout=PIPE) ; result, stderr = p2.communicate() ; print result` Note that you can work with long filenames and shell special characters without having to escape, now that the shell is not involved. Also it's a lot faster since there's one less process.

Comment: @nosklo I'm thinking of situation where you want to grep a regex in a file 13+ million lines long. I tried pythoning the grep part but it was painfully slow compared to grep. Maybe something else was causing the slowness? I gave up playing the python search code pretty quickly.

Comment: @mathtick: yeah, grep is a wonderful piece of software that really goes out of its way to do what it does more efficiently. You can't beat it with python. However it shouldn't be "painfully slow", just slower. Do you have the code you're using posted somewhere? Maybe you want to ask another question here so we can debate if there's something wrong and what the best solution is...

Comment: @nosklo: I'll try to post a clean test of python grep ... it would be nice to understand the speed differences a little better.

Comment: use `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')` instead of `for line in p.stdout` in Python 2 otherwise lines are not read in real time even if the source process doesn't buffer its output.

Comment: The case where I routinely use `shell=True` is big pipelines.  Yeah, just piping through grep is quite arguably not worth it, but chains of 4 or 5 commands aren't rare when doing stuff like bioinfomatics.  It is sometimes tempting to use python replace a bash script... but that is a different thread.

Comment: this bombds with an error for me `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly` in python3

Comment: I do have a use case for `shell=True`: The ability to copy&paste the command to a shell later. So it should be "almost never", not "never".

Comment: @toolforger Sure, you can have infinite use cases if you consider the invalid ones :D I also have a use case: "Being able to say I have a use case" XD XD More seriously though, if you think it is worth invoking an extra useless process and dealing with quoting hell yourself just to be able to copy and paste the command later, go for it, but that doesn't make it a good use case.

Comment: @nosklo Saying you should NEVER use shell=True is needlessly dogmatic. If I have a shell script for my personal use and I am converting it to Python, I'm not going to take the time to manually convert every shell pipeline into the equivalent Python functions. I'm going to cut and paste the pipelines and wrap them in shell strings and run them with shell=True, since those pipelines are "fast enough" as-is.

Answer (score 61):

I know this is an old topic, but there is a solution now. Call the rsync with option --outbuf=L. Example:

```
cmd=['rsync', '-arzv','--backup','--outbuf=L','source/','dest']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print '>>> {}'.format(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: This works and should be upvoted to save future readers from scrolling through all of the dialog above.

Comment: @VectorVictor It doesn't explain what is going on, and why it's going on.
It might be that your program works, until:

1. you add `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` to make the program survive its parent script

2. you skip reading from the process's pipe

3. the process outputs lots of data, filling the pipe

4. you are stuck for hours, trying to figure out why the program you're running quits *after some random amount of time*.

The answer from @nosklo helped me a lot.

Answer (score 33):

Depending on the use case, you might also want to disable the buffering in the subprocess itself.

If the subprocess will be a Python process, you could do this before the call:

```
os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"
```

Or alternatively pass this in the `env` argument to `Popen`.

Otherwise, if you are on Linux/Unix, you can use the `stdbuf` tool. E.g. like:

```
cmd = ["stdbuf", "-oL"] + cmd
```

See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/) about `stdbuf` or other options.

Answer (score 22):

On Linux, I had the same problem of getting rid of the buffering.  I finally used "stdbuf -o0" (or, unbuffer from expect) to get rid of the PIPE buffering.

```
proc = Popen(['stdbuf', '-o0'] + cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout = proc.stdout
```

I could then use select.select on stdout.

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/

Comment: For anyone trying to grab the C code stdout from Python, I can confirm that this solution was the only one that worked for me.  To be clear, I'm talking about adding 'stdbuf', '-o0' to my existing command list in Popen.

Comment: Thank you! `stdbuf -o0` proved to be *really* useful with a bunch of pytest/pytest-bdd tests I wrote that spawn a C++ app and verify that it emits certain log statements. Without `stdbuf -o0`, these tests needed 7 seconds to get the (buffered) output from the C++ program. Now they run almost instantaneously!

Comment: This answer saved me today! Running an application as subprocesses as part of `pytest`, it was impossible for me to get it's output. `stdbuf` does it.

Answer (score 9):

```
for line in p.stdout:
  ...
```

always blocks until the next line-feed.

For "real-time" behaviour you have to do something like this:

```
while True:
  inchar = p.stdout.read(1)
  if inchar: #neither empty string nor None
    print(str(inchar), end='') #or end=None to flush immediately
  else:
    print('') #flush for implicit line-buffering
    break
```

The while-loop is left when the child process closes its stdout or exits.
`read()/read(-1)` would block until the child process closed its stdout or exited.

Comment: `inchar` is never `None` use `if not inchar:` instead (`read()` returns empty string on EOF). btw, It is worse `for line in p.stdout` doesn't print even full lines in realtime in Python 2 (`for line in `iter(p.stdout.readline, '')` could be used instead).

Comment: I have tested this with python 3.4 on osx, and it does not work.

Comment: @qed: `for line in p.stdout:` works on Python 3. Be sure to understand the difference between `''` (Unicode string) and `b''` (bytes). See [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Comment: Some comments are saying "doesn't work", but this is exactly what I wanted to know, thanks, an have an upvote

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is:

```
for line in p.stdout:
    print(">>> " + str(line.rstrip()))
    p.stdout.flush()
```

the iterator itself has extra buffering.

Try doing like this:

```
while True:
  line = p.stdout.readline()
  if not line:
     break
  print line
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                                bufsize=0,
                                universal_newlines=True)
```

I am writing a GUI for rsync in python, and have the same probelms. This problem has troubled me for several days until i find this in pyDoc.

> If universal_newlines is True, the file objects stdout and stderr are opened as text files in universal newlines mode. Lines may be terminated by any of '\n', the Unix end-of-line convention, '\r', the old Macintosh convention or '\r\n', the Windows convention. All of these external representations are seen as '\n' by the Python program.

It seems that rsync will output '\r' when translate is going on.

Comment: Heck, bufsize=0 was all I needed!  Still the most relevant answer for me here.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid caching of output you might wanna try pexpect,

```
child = pexpect.spawn(launchcmd,args,timeout=None)
while True:
    try:
        child.expect('\n')
        print(child.before)
    except pexpect.EOF:
        break
```

**PS** : I know this question is pretty old, still providing the solution which worked for me.

**PPS**: got this answer from another question

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get stdout to print unbuffered to a pipe (unless you can rewrite the program that prints to stdout), so here is my solution:

Redirect stdout to sterr, which is not buffered.  `'<cmd> 1>&2'` should do it.  Open the process as follows: `myproc = subprocess.Popen('<cmd> 1>&2', stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`
You cannot distinguish from stdout or stderr, but you get all output immediately.

Hope this helps anyone tackling this problem.

Comment: Have you tried it? Because it doesn't work.. If stdout is buffered in that process, it won't be redirected to stderr in the same way it isn't redirected to a PIPE or file..

Comment: This is plain wrong.  stdout buffering occurs within the program itself. The shell syntax `1>&2` just changes which files the file-descriptors point to before launching the program.  The program itself can't distinguish between redirecting stdout to stderr (`1>&2`) or vice-versa (`2>&1`) so this will have no effect on the buffering behaviour of the program.And either way the `1>&2` syntax is interpreted by the shell.  `subprocess.Popen('<cmd> 1>&2', stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` would fail because you haven't specified `shell=True`.

Comment: In case people would be reading this: I tried using stderr instead of stdout, it shows the exact same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

if you run something like this in a thread and save the ffmpeg_time property in a property of a method so you can access it, it would work very nice
I get outputs like this:
[output be like if you use threading in tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLhdM.png)

```
input = 'path/input_file.mp4'
output = 'path/input_file.mp4'
command = "ffmpeg -y -v quiet -stats -i \"" + str(input) + "\" -metadata title=\"@alaa_sanatisharif\" -preset ultrafast -vcodec copy -r 50 -vsync 1 -async 1 \"" + output + "\""
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
for line in self.process.stdout:
    reg = re.search('\d\d:\d\d:\d\d', line)
    ffmpeg_time = reg.group(0) if reg else ''
    print(ffmpeg_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the stdout from the rsync process to be unbuffered.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     shell=True,
                     bufsize=0,  # 0=unbuffered, 1=line-buffered, else buffer-size
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Buffering happens on the rsync side, changing bufsize attribute on python side won't help.

Comment: For anyone else searching, nosklo's answer is completely wrong:  rsync's progress display is not buffered; the real problem is that subprocess returns a file object and the file iterator interface has a poorly documented internal buffer even with bufsize=0, requiring you to call readline() repeatedly if you need results before the buffer fills.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that there is no mention of using a temporary file as intermediate.  The following gets around the buffering issues by outputting to a temporary file and allows you to parse the data coming from rsync without connecting to a pty.  I tested the following on a linux box, and the output of rsync tends to differ across platforms, so the regular expressions to parse the output may vary:

```
import subprocess, time, tempfile, re

pipe_output, file_name = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
cmd = ["rsync", "-vaz", "-P", "/src/" ,"/dest"]

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=pipe_output, 
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while p.poll() is None:
    # p.poll() returns None while the program is still running
    # sleep for 1 second
    time.sleep(1)
    last_line =  open(file_name).readlines()
    # it's possible that it hasn't output yet, so continue
    if len(last_line) == 0: continue
    last_line = last_line[-1]
    # Matching to "[bytes downloaded]  number%  [speed] number:number:number"
    match_it = re.match(".* ([0-9]*)%.* ([0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*).*", last_line)
    if not match_it: continue
    # in this case, the percentage is stored in match_it.group(1), 
    # time in match_it.group(2).  We could do something with it here...
```

Comment: it is not in real time. A file doesn't solve buffering issue on rsync's side.

Comment: tempfile.TemporaryFile can delete itself for easier clean up in case of exceptions

Comment: `while not p.poll()` leads to infinite loop if subprocess exits successfully with 0, use `p.poll() is  None` instead

Comment: Windows might forbid to open already opened file, so `open(file_name)` might fail

Comment: I just found this answer, unfortunately only for linux, but works like a charm
[link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/25378#25378)

So i just extend my command as follows:

`command_argv = ["stdbuf","-i0","-o0","-e0"] + command_argv`
and call:
`popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

and now I can read from without any buffering

Answer (score -2):

In Python 3, here's a solution, which takes a command off the command line and delivers real-time nicely decoded strings as they are received.

Receiver (`receiver.py`):

```
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = sys.argv[1:]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.stdout:
    print("received: {}".format(line.rstrip().decode("utf-8")))
```

Example simple program that could generate real-time output (`dummy_out.py`):

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(5):
    print("hello {}".format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()  
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
$python receiver.py python dummy_out.py
received: hello 0
received: hello 1
received: hello 2
received: hello 3
received: hello 4
```