# Reading stderr of subprocess while it is executing

Tags: python, buffer, subprocess, stderr

I'd like to read what is written to stderr by a subprocess while it is executing.

However, when I use this script that I've written, stderr does not seem to have anything for me to read until the subprocess has exited.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Please provide a command"
    sys.exit(1)

sub = Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

for i, line in enumerate(sub.stdout):
    sys.stdout.write("%d: %s" % (i, line))
```

**edit:**

Ok, I've gotten closer now. If I specify the number of bytes to read it overcomes the buffering.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Please provide a command"
    sys.exit(1)

sub = Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

i = 0 
while sub.poll() is None:
    line = sub.stdout.read(64)
    line.strip("\b")
    sys.stdout.write("%d: %s\n" % (i, line))
    i += 1
```

Snippet of output:

```
58:  86 q=21.0 size= 4541841kB time=00:00:22.08 bitrate=1685014.2kbi
frame=  567 fps= 86 q=22.0 size= 4543667kB time=00:00:2
frame=  621 fps= 87 q=20.0 sizs/s    
frame= 4545352kB time=00:00:26.11 bitrate=1425939.2kbits/s    
62: =  686 fps= 90 q=12.0 size= 4546970kB time=00:00:28.89 bitrate=1
frame=  758 fps= 93 q=25.0 size= 4548534kB t
frame=  794 fps= 92 bitrate=1168185.5kbits/s    
65:  q=27.0 size= 4550901kB time=00:00:33.40 bitrate=1115897.0kbits/
frame=  827 fps= 91 q=27.0 size= 4552324kB time=00:00:34.7
frame=  857 fps= 89 q=26.0 size=  
frame=  254kB time=00:00:36.12 bitrate=1032874.9kbits/s    
69: 892 fps= 88 q=25.0 size= 4556598kB time=00:00:37.36 bitrate=9988
frame=  948 fps= 89 q=19.0 size= 4558565kB time=
frame= 1006 fps= 90 q=19937320.4kbits/s    
72: .0 size= 4560139kB time=00:00:42.16 bitrate=885880.0kbits/s    
73: frame= 1060 fps= 91 q=19.0 size= 4561958kB time=00:00:44.49 bitr
frame= 1122 fps= 93 q=18.0 size= 4563460
frame= 1173 fps=0:47.08 bitrate=793898.4kbits/s
```

It looks like my problem now is that ffmpeg is using backspace characters or similar to mess with stdout. Not sure what's happening here.

Comment: What process are you using? It is most likely buffering it's output when connected to a pipe.

Comment: See [catching stdout in realtime from subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1606795)

Comment: The process is ffmpeg, I am trying to read the fps during conversion

Comment: Would [Turn off buffering in pipe](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372) help?

Comment: You've solved the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use [sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh) module. It is very nice piece of software which wraps subprocesses in python and gives you pythonic, beautiful interface which you will love. Look at the [docs](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/).

If you really do not want `sh` module, use [communicate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method of `Popen`

Answer (score 1):

You should use PIPE for both, also, you need to call `communicate()`:

```
sub = Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, error_output = sub.communicate()

print 'OUTPUT:'
print output

print 'ERROR:'
print error_output
```

Comment: Why is that? Redirecting `stderr` to stdout is fine, and not the issue.

Comment: In this case, it is not an issue. In general, you might want to separate them to know if there is any error occurred. I failed to mention the missing `communicate()`, which is essential to fix the original poster's problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the subprocess [doesn't use block-buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python#comment18358805_95246) then you could try:

```
for i, line in enumerate(iter(sub.stdout.readline, b"")):
    print i, line,
```