# Print l2ping output in real time using Python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, bluez

I'm trying to integrate l2ping with Python (2.7). l2ping is a tool from blueZ package, running on linux, that performs echo request to a bluetooth device.

I want to show (or store in a variable) the output of the echo request in real time.

I have read a lot of discussion in this community, but (in my case) all the solutions show the result only at the end of the pinging process.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

mac_addr=  'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' //my real bluetooth mac address
process = subprocess.Popen(['unbuffer', 'l2ping', '-c', '3', mac_addr], bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

while True:
    print "debug"
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    else:
        print line
```

As I previously said, my code show the output but all in one time at the end of the process.
The program goes till the "debug" line and then it stops, wait the end of l2ping and prints out all the output.

I've also try to use `bufsize=0`, or `stdout.flush()` but no output are shown in real time. Also, `communicate()` nor `check_output()` don't work for me.

I think that `l2ping` command is quite different from some others, in fact it does not write immediately on stdout and this can cause the specific problem.

What I'm doing wrong? How can I read in real time the output of l2ping?

**EDIT**: I've found a solution that works fine for me. I use the command `unbuffer` when I call `l2ping`. I've edit the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printing stdout in realtime from a subprocess that requires stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411966/printing-stdout-in-realtime-from-a-subprocess-that-requires-stdin)

Comment: @MadPhysicist It isn't a duplicate, in my case the answer is not working due to the use of `l2ping`

Comment: What does `l2ping` do different from any normal process?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The fact that a code that works with all others process doesn't work with l2ping. If I have known the answer I don't write here...

Comment: Fair enough. So that's the question then. What makes the output of `l2ping` different? Does it itself detect that it is writing to a pipe and buffer it? Because at this point, it's the only thing I can think of.