# Python 2 to 3 conversion: iterating over lines in subprocess stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have the following Python 2 example code that I want to make compatible with Python 3:

```
call = 'for i in {1..5}; do sleep 1; echo "Hello $i"; done'
p = subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line, end='')
```

This works well in Python 2 but in Python 3 `p.stdout` does not allow me to specify an encoding and reading it will return byte strings, rather than Unicode, so the comparison with `''` will always return false and `iter` won't stop. [This issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue6135) seems to imply that in Python 3.6 there'll be a way to define this encoding.

For now, I have changed the `iter` call to stop when it finds an empty bytes string `iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')`, which seems to work in 2 and 3. My questions are: Is this safe in both 2 and 3? Is there a better way of ensuring compatibility?

Note: I'm not using `for line in p.stdout:` because I need each line to be printed as it's generated and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17395353/189418) `p.stdout` has a too large a buffer.

Comment: FYI. I tried your code in Ubuntu against Python 2, I get: `Hello {1..5}`

Comment: Add `executable='/bin/bash'` to the `Popen` call will help to get the correct output. I am still investigating why the failure in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks @HaiVu, I ran it on a Mac and in CentOS, both with bash, and it worked with no need to specify the executable. When I try it in Ubuntu I see the same as you, no idea why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `unversal_newlines=True`.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line, end='')
```

Instead of `bytes`, `str` will be returned so `''` will work in both situations.

Here is what the docs have to say about the option:

> If universal_newlines is False the file objects stdin, stdout and
>   stderr will be opened as binary streams, and no line ending conversion
>   is done.
>
> If universal_newlines is True, these file objects will be opened as
>   text streams in universal newlines mode using the encoding returned by
>   locale.getpreferredencoding(False). For stdin, line ending characters
>   '\n' in the input will be converted to the default line separator
>   os.linesep. For stdout and stderr, all line endings in the output will
>   be converted to '\n'. For more information see the documentation of
>   the io.TextIOWrapper class when the newline argument to its
>   constructor is None.

It's not explicitly called out about the `bytes` versus `str` difference, but it is implied by stating that `False` returns a binary stream and `True` returns a text stream.

Comment: I literally had this problem just 3 days ago in a program I converted to Python 3.

Comment: Isn't it weird that an option with a name that implies handling of newlines, modifies the format of the whole output (bytes vs str)? Seems like a weird side effect, or bad naming of the argument. Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Gauthier Yes, it is very weird. In newer versions of Python there is now the alternate name `text` which was added to correct the weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `p.communicate()` and then decode it if it is a `bytes` object:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess

def b(t):
    if isinstance(t, bytes):
        return t.decode("utf8")
    return t

call = 'for i in {1..5}; do sleep 1; echo "Hello $i"; done'
p = subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

for line in iter(b(stdout).splitlines(), ''):
    print(line, end='')
```

This would work in both Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: The problem with `communicate` is it will wait till the subprocess is complete before returning the stdout. It this the intended behavior it is a good solution, but if the subprocess is long running or would generate multiple GB of output this may not be desired.