# How to process stdout from subprocess but still allow termination at some timeout

Tags: python, stdout, python-3.3

There are a number of questions and answers related to Python subprocess and reading of stdout during execution, but still I have not found a solution that fulfills these requirements:

- Start a subprocess
- Print stdout to terminal, while doing other processing e.g. writing to file
- Print stderr to terminal, while doing other processing e.g. writing to file
- stdout and stderr must be handled separately
- Termination of process if output indicates error or due to some timeout
- Linux must be supported, and if possible also Windows (XP/7)

One obstacle is for example that process stdout.read() and stdout.readline() are blocking if no stdout data is generated by the running process, thereby preventing process kill() for termination due to a timeout.

Code for a start:

```
# Python 3.3 syntax

import sys
import subprocess

def subproc(args, stdout):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, universal_newlines=True)
    while True:  # while is broken by return 
        try:
            outs = ''  # Clear before communication attempt
            outs = proc.communicate(timeout=1)[0]  # Timeout every second to process stdout
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            pass
        # Processing termination using proc.kill is added later
        sys.__stdout__.write('Shows that proc communicate timeout works\n')
        if outs:
            stdout.write(outs)  # Allow stdout processing
        if proc.returncode is not None:  # Completed execution
            return proc.returncode  # End while and return

class StdHandle:
    def write(self, str):
        # Additional processing ...
        sys.__stdout__.write(str)
    def flush(self):
        pass

rc = subproc(('proc.sh'), stdout=StdHandle())
print('Return code:', rc)

# EOF
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795/catching-stdout-in-realtime-from-subprocess

Comment: You just want it to redirect to stdout? Nothing more?

Comment: It should go to normal stdout, but also allow for processing of output, for example to determine termination.

Comment: To avoid the blocking calls to `read()`/`readline()` simply use the `select` module.

Comment: @doctorlove: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795 is related, but uses readline(), which then hangs if there is not output from the process, as for what I understand.

Comment: @Bakuriu: What function should I look at in the `select` module ?  Do you know if it will work both for Linux and Windows ?

Comment: @MortenZdk AFAIK `select` is not available on Windows. The `select` function can be used to test whether you can read/write to a given `socket`/`file`.

Comment: Errata: on windows you cannot use `select` with files(which is what you want), but you can use it with `socket`s.