# Capturing stdout of subprocess realtime in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, real-time, stdout

I want to run my command and capture stdout realtime:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
cmd='my command'
args=shlex.split(cmd)    
com=subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
com.stdout.flush()
for line in com.stdout.read()
    print line
```

But there is nothing as output...

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795/catching-stdout-in-realtime-from-subprocess)?

Answer (score 1):

`read()` reads until `EOF` (which does not usually happen until subprocess exit), to get more 'realtime' at least read by lines via `readline()` in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Any object connected to a file descriptor can be passed to `subprocess.Popen` including `sys.stdout`!

```
com=subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=sys.stdout,stderr=sys.stderr)
```

Note that this may not work in some python shells.

Comment: Error: IndexError: list index out of range @ppperry

Comment: That error makes no sense in the context of my answer, which does not do any kind of list indexing. Please show the full traceback

Comment: This is output: `
    tcpdump=subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=sys.stdout,stderr=sys.stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1206, in _execute_child
    executable = args[0]
`

Comment: You are passing an empty list to the `subprocess.Popen` constructor. This has nothing to do with output redirection.

Comment: there is no need to use `stdout=sys.stdout`. By default the standard output is inherited i.e., if you you don't pass `stdout` parameter then the child process prints to the same place as the parent Python script (unless `sys.stdout` is replaced incorrectly).