# How to continually communicate with same process with Python Popen()

Tags: python, unix

I am new at this so hope you understand...

Now I am using python subprocess module for sending the specific command.

After I send the command1 with Popen function, I would like to send a command2 to same process one more.

Is it possible...?

```
// Example
// command1 -> Opening command for text program.
// command2 -> Executing the write and save command.(on above text program) 

popen = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
// next....?
```

please let me know If I understand it incorrectly.

Comment: Does command 1 output is sent to command 2?

Comment: No, these command are executed respectively.
command1 - Executing the program wating the user's specific input.

Comment: command2 - specific input for program.
For example
C program using scanf function.
Executing command1 -> scanf("%d", &a)
Executing command2 -> 12345 (+Enter)

Comment: If you want to communicate with a process many times, you can make it listen and write to named pipes.

Comment: @ Eli Korvigo you mean FIFO (named pipe)... right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out.
In unix, we can execute multiple commands in one go like

```
cmd_1;cmd_2
```

We will use same thing with sub-process.

Make sure to use `shell=True`.

```
import subprocess
all_cmd = "echo a;echo b;echo c"

p = subprocess.Popen(all_cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
p_stdout,p_err = p.communicate()
print p_stdout.strip()
```

Comment: You'll generally want to avoid `shell=True` and use some other mechanism.

Comment: @tripleee - Ya I am aware of security concern. Also , after reading comments from OP, I think my above solution won't work for him. pexpect or exscript will be useful to him.

Comment: If you recommend `shell=True` you will also want to explain the caveats.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly doable but you might want to look into something like `pexpect` which offers more control over the dialog.

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(['command1'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)  # no shell=True here!
stdout, stderr = cmd.communicate('command2')
```

This presumes that `command1` will keep running and reading additional commands on its standard input.

Answer (score 0):

For **catching stdout in realtime from subprocess** better check [catching stdout in realtime from subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795/catching-stdout-in-realtime-from-subprocess)