# Use python's pty to create a live console

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, pty

I'm trying to create an execution environment/shell that will remotely execute on a server, which streams the stdout,err,in over the socket to be rendered in a browser. I currently have tried the approach of using `subprocess.run` with a `PIPE`. The Problem is that I get the stdout after the process has completed. What i want to achieve is to get a line-by-line, pseudo-terminal sort of implementation.

My current implementation

> test.py

```
def greeter():
    for _ in range(10):
        print('hello world')

greeter()
```

and in the shell

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> result = subprocess.run(['python3', 'test.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

If i try to attempt even this simple implementation with `pty`, how does one do it?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795/catching-stdout-in-realtime-from-subprocess

Comment: Try using `bufsize=1` parameter to subprocess to set line buffer, and use `iter(result.stdout.readline, b'')` to read the stdout wrapped in while True loop

Answer (score 6):

If your application is going to work asynchronously with multiple tasks, like reading data from stdout and then writing it to a websocket, I suggest using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#asyncio).

Here is an example that runs a process and redirects its output into a websocket:

```py
import asyncio.subprocess
import os

from aiohttp.web import (Application, Response, WebSocketResponse, WSMsgType,
                         run_app)


async def on_websocket(request):
    # Prepare aiohttp's websocket...
    resp = WebSocketResponse()
    await resp.prepare(request)
    # ... and store in a global dictionary so it can be closed on shutdown
    request.app['sockets'].append(resp)

    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(sys.executable,
                                                   '/tmp/test.py',
                                                    stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
                                                    stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
                                                    bufsize=0)
    # Schedule reading from stdout and stderr as asynchronous tasks.
    stdout_f = asyncio.ensure_future(p.stdout.readline())
    stderr_f = asyncio.ensure_future(p.stderr.readline())

    # returncode will be set upon process's termination.
    while p.returncode is None:
        # Wait for a line in either stdout or stderr.
        await asyncio.wait((stdout_f, stderr_f), return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

        # If task is done, then line is available.
        if stdout_f.done():
            line = stdout_f.result().encode()
            stdout_f = asyncio.ensure_future(p.stdout.readline())
            await ws.send_str(f'stdout: {line}')

        if stderr_f.done():
            line = stderr_f.result().encode()
            stderr_f = asyncio.ensure_future(p.stderr.readline())
            await ws.send_str(f'stderr: {line}')

    return resp


async def on_shutdown(app):
    for ws in app['sockets']:
        await ws.close()    


async def init(loop):
    app = Application()
    app['sockets'] = []
    app.router.add_get('/', on_websocket)
    app.on_shutdown.append(on_shutdown)
    return app


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
app = loop.run_until_complete(init())
run_app(app)
```

It uses [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io) and is based on the [web_ws](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/examples/web_ws.py) and [subprocess streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocess-using-streams) examples.

Answer (score 5):

Im sure theres a dupe around somewhere but i couldnt find it quickly

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=0)

for out in iter(process.stdout.readline, b""):
    print(out)
```

Comment: this would still wait for the `cmd` to finish and then the for loop will start. I want more of an async implementation, that's why I want to know more about `pty`

Comment: this should stream it in realtime ... you might want to set your buffersize to zero if you are not finding this to be the case

Comment: @IshanKhare> this **will** stream in realtime. The `Popen` function starts the program in the background and returns immediately. Anything the program outputs will be read immediately. Note that the reads are buffered though, so the reads will return once a large enough chunk has been read (that's why if you test with too simple examples you could think it waits). You can disable buffering with `bufsize=0` if you really want fully realtime reads at the expense of performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows then you will be fighting an uphill battle for a very long time, and I am sorry for the pain you will endure (been there). If you are on Linux, however, you can use the [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module. Pexpect allows you to spawn a background child process which you can perform bidirectional communication with. This is useful for all types of system automation, but a very common use case is ssh.

```
import pexpect

child   = pexpect.spawn('python3 test.py')
message = 'hello world'

while True:
    try:
        child.expect(message)
    except pexpect.exceptions.EOF:
        break
    input('child sent: "%s"\nHit enter to continue: ' %
         (message + child.before.decode()))

print('reached end of file!')
```

I have found it very useful to create a class to handle something complicated like an ssh connection, but if your use case is simple enough that might not be appropriate or necessary. The way pexpect.before is of type bytes and omits the pattern you are searching for can be awkward, so it may make sense to create a function that handles this for you at the very least.

```
def get_output(child, message):
    return(message + child.before.decode())
```

If you want to send messages to the child process, you can use child.sendline(line). For more details, check out the documentation I linked.

I hope I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can render this in a browser, but you can run a program like module so you get stdout immediately like this:

```
import importlib
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

class Program:

    def __init__(self, path, name=''):
        self.path = path
        self.name = name
        if self.path:
            if not self.name:
                self.get_name()
            self.loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(self.name, self.path)
            self.spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(self.loader.name, self.loader)
            self.mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(self.spec)
        return

    def get_name(self):
        extension = '.py' #change this if self.path is not python program with extension .py
        self.name = self.path.split('\\')[-1].strip('.py')
        return

    def load(self):
        self.check()
        self.loader.exec_module(self.mod)
        return

    def check(self):
        if not self.path:
            Error('self.file is NOT defined.'.format(path)).throw()
        return

file_path = 'C:\\Users\\RICHGang\\Documents\\projects\\stackoverflow\\ptyconsole\\test.py'
file_name = 'test'
prog = Program(file_path, file_name)   
prog.load()
```

You can add sleep in test.py to see the difference:

```
from time import sleep

def greeter():
    for i in range(10):
        sleep(0.3)
        print('hello world')

greeter()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at terminado. Works on Windows and Linux.

Jupiter Lab uses it.