# run long time subprocess and get stdout before the end of the execution

Tags: python

I need to run a long time command and get the output in live.

As an example, in the above code, I would like to get the "hello" stdout before waiting 20s to terminate the command:

```
import subprocess
script = '''"
import time
print('hello')
time.sleep(20)
print('OK')
"'''
process = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Do you have any idea ? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [catching stdout in realtime from subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795/catching-stdout-in-realtime-from-subprocess)

Comment: Thank you, Yes it helped me to get it :)