# Qt parent mechanism

Tags: c++, qt

There is one `QPushButton` in a `QWidget`, `click` the button should open another `QWidget`, as coded below:

project.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = debug
} else {
    DESTDIR = release
}

INCLUDEPATH += ..

SOURCES += ../main.cpp\
           ../widget.cpp \
           ../secondwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += ../widget.h \
            ../secondwidget.h
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

#include "secondwidget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    resize(400, 300);
    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QPushButton *bt = new QPushButton("Open 2nd Widget");
    vLayout->addWidget(bt, 1, Qt::AlignRight);

    SecondWidget *secondWidget = new SecondWidget();
//    SecondWidget *secondWidget = new SecondWidget(this);
    connect(bt, &QPushButton::clicked, secondWidget, &SecondWidget::show);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}
```

secondwidget.h

```
#ifndef SECONDWIDGET_H
#define SECONDWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class SecondWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SecondWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // SECONDWIDGET_H
```

secondwidget.cpp

```
#include "secondwidget.h"

SecondWidget::SecondWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false );
}
```

Passing `this` for the `SecondWidget` constructor (as in the commented line) will brake my logic at some point. So the `SecondWidget` doesn't show anymore, when the button is clicked.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the problems with your destructor and constructor (and the memory leak you have because of the second), and the project file here are a few things that you may want to know in order to understand the whole parent situation:

You don't need to pass `this`. The purpose of assigning a parent is to be able to simplify the cleanup procedure for `QObject` instances (including all classes inheriting from the `QObject` class). Qt parent-child model follows the C++ standard that is **destructors** are invoked in the reversed order of their **constructors**. In simple terms this means the following:

Imagine you create **widget A, B and C**. Using the parent property you assign **B** and **C** to be children of **A**. So here we have the order of creation:

1. A (parent)
2. B,C (children)

Now at some point you want to destroy your widgets (example: closing the application). The standard C++ way is to destroy them in the following (reversed to the construction) order:

1. B, C (children)
2. A (parent)

And this is indeed what happens if we go for the parent first. However we are dealing with Qt here so we have to consider one additional feature the library provides - slots and signals.

Whenever a `QObject` gets destroyed it emits a signal. Based on the role the object plays in the parent-child relationship the outcome is one of the following:

- **only the `QObject` that is destroyed gets destroyed** - this is what happens when a child gets destroyed before we destroy its parent
- **all children of that** `QObject` **get destroyed first followed by the destruction of the** `QObject` **itself** - this is what happens when a parent gets destroyed. The emitted signal is caught by all its children which in return also get eliminated.

However assigning a parent is not mandatory. You can do the cleanup manually yourself. Read more about the parent-child model in the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html).

In addition to all that ownership transfer (a widget becomes a child of another widget) often happens automatically so it is not necessary to explicitly specify a widget's parent. Again taking things out of the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts) an exception is made here. If you add a widget to a layout, the ownership is NOT transferred to the layout itself but to the `QWidget` it is part of.

Finally there is one important case when not assigning a parent makes things very, very different. Here I shall quote the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#QObject) on `QObject`:

> Setting parent to 0 constructs an object with no parent. **If the object is a widget, it will become a top-level window.**

So if you have a `QWidget` and don't add it to some layout (and indirectly to the `QWidget` that has that layout) for example it will automatically become a separate window.

---

**EDIT:**
Check your constructor and in particular the way you work with your `secondWidget` object. As I've mentioned above in case you don't want to assign it to a parent widget **you** need to take care of the cleaning.

You dynamically allocate the memory for it

```
    SecondWidget *secondWidget = new SecondWidget();
```

and even connect it to your button

```
    connect(bt, &QPushButton::clicked, secondWidget, &SecondWidget::show);
```

however you never release the allocated memory using `delete` or assigning it to a parent widget, which will take care of it automatically. Hence you create a memory leak. Connecting a `QObject` via signals and slots doesn't have anything to do with transfer of ownership.

I personally assume that you actually want a `secondWidget` to be an extra window shown on the screen. In this case you need to create a class member of type `SecondWidget`

```
SecondWidget *secondWidget;
```

then allocate it inside your constructor and connect whichever slots and signals you want

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
  //...
  secondWidget = new SecondWidget();
  connect(bt, &QPushButton::clicked, secondWidget, &SecondWidget::show);
}
```

and finally release the memory inside your constructor:

```
Widget::~Widget()
{
  delete secondWidget;
}
```

Otherwise as I said you are basically creating a reference to a memory block and right after you leave your constructor that reference gets destroyed since it runs out of scope.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a small example how to do it if you want `secondWidget` as a child to your main widget:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  Widget w;
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

**widget.hpp**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "secondwidget.h"

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~Widget();

private:
  Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  SecondWidget *secondWidget = new SecondWidget(this); # secondWidget is now officially adopted by Widget
  # If you skip the parent assignment inside SecondWidget you can call secondWidget->setParent(this) here
  connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), secondWidget, SLOT(show()));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

**secondwidget.hpp**

```
#ifndef SECONDWIDGET_H
#define SECONDWIDGET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDialog>

class SecondWidget : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit SecondWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~SecondWidget();
};

#endif // SECONDWIDGET_H
```

**secondwidget.cpp**

```
#include "secondwidget.h"
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QLabel>

SecondWidget::SecondWidget(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
  # If you don't call the constructor of your superclass you can still assign a parent by invoking setParent(parent) here
  QFormLayout *layout = new QFormLayout();
  QLabel *label = new QLabel("SecondWidget here");
  layout->addWidget(label); # Transfer ownership of label to SecondWidget
  setLayout(layout);
}

SecondWidget::~SecondWidget()
{

}
```

Note the `setParent(parent)` inside the `SecondWidget`'s constructor. You either have to invoke the superclass constructor (as you have done) or manually call `setParent(parent). If you don't do that your`secondWidget`will not be assigned as a child to your main widget where you create it and thus you will produce a memory leak. You can also invoke`secondWidget->setParent(this)` from within the constructor of your main widget in order to set the parent.

Here is how you can check if the parent-child hierarchy is okay:

- To each `QObject` that you have (`QWidget`, `QLayout` etc. are all subclasses of `QObject`) assign an object name using `QObject::setObjectName("some name")`
- At the end of both of your constructors add:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < this->children().count(); i++)
    std::cout << this->children()[i]->objectName().toStdString() << std::endl; // Add #include <iostream> to get the output
  ```

  which basically traverses all the children of `this` (`Widget` or `SecondWidget`) and displays its children. In my case I got

  ```
      label              // Printing out children of SecondWidget
      formLayout         // Printing out children of SecondWidget
      gridLayout         // Printing out children of Widget
      pushButton         // Printing out children of Widget
      main second widget // Printing out children of Widget
  ```

once I launched my application.

**EDIT 3:** Ah, I didn't notice that you are calling the `QWidget(parent)` in you `SecondWidget` constructor. This also does the trick so you don't need `setParent(parent)`. I have altered my second EDIT.

Comment: Would you mind to explicitly point where are the "problems with your destructor (and the memory leak you have because of it)"?

Comment: I tough I could do `secondWidget = new SecondWidget(this);` and forget about `delete secondWidget;`. So isn't possible to avoid the explicit `delete secondWidget;`?

Comment: I see no `this` in the parentheses. If you don't assign a parent to your `QObject` (a `QWidget` is derived from `QObject`) as I've written in my post you need to take care of the clean up yourself because the instance you have created is all on its own. You can always check using `valgrind` what's happening with the memory allocation if unsure. So either add your `secondWidget` as a child or outsource it as a class member and take care of the cleanup inside the destructor.

Comment: But you see `this` in the commented line (`//    SecondWidget *secondWidget = new SecondWidget(this);`)? I'm trying to use the commented line instead of the one before it. But going this way, when I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: Check my answer for further details. You are missing the `setParent(...)`. I have explained where to put it and how it affects your code.

Comment: I have misread your constructor of `SecondWidget`. I have fixed my last code.

Comment: Going to the end... Should I conclude that if `SecondWidget` is explicit parented by doing `new SecondWidget(this)` then it will always reside inside the primary widget? And if I want `SecondWidget` to be another window then it should be made without parent?

Comment: Yes. Also you can always check something like that out by simply trying putting in your code and seeing what happens (best way to learn stuff omho). For example I just added this to `secondWidget` in my code on my computer. Upon execution the widget was embedded inside the main widget. It looked weird since it wasn't part of the layout but it was there.  You should use `hide()` in your main widget or otherwise `secondWidget` will be painted over it (even though you haven't triggered `show()`). It's basically viewed as `QLabel` or similar. You don't need explicitly `show()` a label. :)

Comment: Great! Since `SecondWidget` has no child widgets I didn't noticed it being shown in the primary window when parented :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if

classes are linked

destructor calls aren't properly being called

Makefile needs some changes.

Answer (score 1):

Actual Error?

1. Makefile needs to be remade using the cmd prompt or Terminal
2. Make sure that your destructor doesn't call itself so this change the remedy of execution.