# Display Popen.communicate() in real time

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am trying to run

`proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

with the output being monitored with comm = proc.communicate(). This works fine, in that I can print comm[0] or comm[1] and get all of the output, but it doesn't work in real time, only all at the end of the process.

Is there a way to have the stability of communicate() with the speed of just running something like proc.stdout.readline()? I get clogged (as the python manual suggests I might) when I try to use proc.stdout.readline().

Comment: do you want to separate stdout from stderr? what do you mean by "stability" ?

Comment: Try using shell parametrs in constructor.
proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085071/real-time-intercepting-of-stdout-from-another-process-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874815/how-do-i-get-real-time-information-back-from-a-subprocess-popen-in-python-2-5

Comment: @ZhekaKoval The `shell` parameter has nothing to do with the output of the command once it runs.