# Unbuffered read from process using subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to read from a process that produces long and time-consuming output. However, I want to catch it's output *as and when* it is produced. But using something like the following seems to be buffering the command's output, so I end up getting the output lines all at once:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
    for line in p.stdout:
        print line
```

I am trying this on MacOS 10.5

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874815/how-do-i-get-real-time-information-back-from-a-subprocess-popen-in-python-2-5, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527197/intercepting-stdout-of-a-subprocess-while-it-is-running

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The file iterator is doing some internal buffering [on its own](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.next). Try this:

```
line = p.stdout.readline()
while line:
    print line
    line = p.stdout.readline()
```

You also need to make sure the process you are running is actually flushing its output buffers frequently.

Comment: You also need to make sure the process you are running is actually flushing its output buffers frequently. I debugged more than half day to find out that stdout has quite a big buffer when directed into a pipe. So I had to add some flushes into the program's code to make the output actually appear.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, every program will do more buffering on its input and/or output channels than you appear to desire... unless it's fooled into believing said channel's actually a terminal!

For that "fooling in a good cause" purpose, use [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) -- it works just fine on a Mac (life is harder on Windows, though there are solutions that might help even there - fortunately we don't need to dwell on those as you use a Mac instead).

Answer (score 3):

This was actually a bug that's fixed in Python 2.6: http://bugs.python.org/issue3907

Comment: On python 2.7 `for line in p.stdout` still delays its output while `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')` works as expected (it produces lines as soon as they are available).

Comment: Sorry, 2.x won't use the new io library by default, as the last comment on the bug report says; You'd have to do something like `for line in io.open(p.stdin.fileno())`.

Comment: @Ari: Should that be `for line in io.open(p.stdout.fileno())`?