# How to use pipes in python without blocking?

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess, popen

In python, I want to create a subprocess and read and write data to its stdio.
Lets say I have the following C program that just writes its input to its output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char c;
    for(;;) {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

In python I should be able to use this using the subprocess module. Something like this:

```
from subprocess import *
pipe = Popen("thing", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
pipe.stdin.write("blah blah blah")
text = pipe.stdout.read(4) # text should == "blah"
```

However in this case the call to read blocks indefinitely.
How can I do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

stdout is line-buffered when writing to a terminal, but fully buffered when writing to a pipe so your output isn't being seen immediately.

To flush the buffer, call `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf()`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527197/intercepting-stdout-of-a-subprocess-while-it-is-running) which is the same except that your subprocess is written in C, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default) which references stdin/stdout behaviour as defined in C99.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) module which does exactly what I need.