# Redirecting stdout to "nothing" in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a large project consisting of sufficiently large number of modules, each printing something to the standard output. Now as the project has grown in size, there are large no. of `print` statements printing a lot on the std out which has made the program considerably slower.

So, I now want to decide at *runtime* whether or not to print anything to the stdout. I cannot make changes in the modules as there are plenty of them. (I know I can redirect the stdout to a file but even this is considerably slow.)

So my question is how do I redirect the stdout to nothing ie how do I make the `print` statement do nothing?

```
# I want to do something like this.
sys.stdout = None         # this obviously will give an error as Nonetype object does not have any write method.
```

Currently the only idea I have is to make a class which has a write method (which does nothing) and redirect the stdout to an instance of this class.

```
class DontPrint(object):
    def write(*args): pass

dp = DontPrint()
sys.stdout = dp
```

Is there an inbuilt mechanism in python for this? Or is there something better than this?

Comment: related: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279)

Comment: I've just discovered a peculiar thing. Turning sys.stdout into None actually works in my program, although I'm not sure why. I was having *really* weird problems with encoding redirecting to os.devnull so I tried just using None, and it works. Might have something to do with me doing it in a Django unit test, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Teekin It does indeed work, and in contexts that have nothing to do with Django.

Comment: This question is a combination of [How to capture stdout output from a Python function call? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call) and [Cross platform /dev/null in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929899/cross-platform-dev-null-in-python), but there exists a **more efficient solution in this special case**, see below.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Cross-platform:

```
import os
import sys
f = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stdout = f
```

On Windows:

```
f = open('nul', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
```

On Linux:

```
f = open('/dev/null', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
```

Comment: How do you then cancel it? Is there a way to turn print statements back on after you are done?

Comment: Sure, just save a reference to the original `sys.stdout` and set it back after.  For example `old_stdout = sys.stdout` before any of the other code, then `sys.stdout = old_stdout` when you are done.

Comment: note: it doesn't redirect at a file descriptor level i.e., it may fail to redirect the output of external child processes, the output from C extensions that print to C stdout directly, `os.write(1, b'abc\n')`. You need `os.dup2()`, to redirect at the file descriptor level, see [`stdout_redirected()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)

Comment: Note there is `sys.__stdout__` for cancelling a redirection. So you just do `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` and no need to store the backup.

Comment: Note: Cleaner than `sys.stout = f` is `with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)

Answer (score 53):

A nice way to do this is to create a small context processor that you wrap your prints in. You then just use is in a `with`-statement to silence all output.

**Python 2:**

```
import os
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def silence_stdout():
    old_target = sys.stdout
    try:
        with open(os.devnull, "w") as new_target:
            sys.stdout = new_target
            yield new_target
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_target

with silence_stdout():
    print("will not print")

print("this will print")
```

**Python 3.4+:**

Python 3.4 has a context processor like this built-in, so you can simply use contextlib like this:

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    print("will not print")

print("this will print")
```

---

If the code you want to surpress writes directly to sys.stdout using None as redirect target won't work. Instead you can use:

```
import contextlib
import sys
import os

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(open(os.devnull, 'w')):
    sys.stdout.write("will not print")

sys.stdout.write("this will print")
```

---

If your code writes to stderr instead of stdout, you can use contextlib.redirect_stderr instead of redirect_stdout.

---

Running this code only prints the second line of output, not the first:

```
$ python test.py
this will print
```

This works cross-platform (Windows + Linux + Mac OSX), and is cleaner than the ones other answers imho.

Comment: @celticminstrel you are totally right, thanks for correcting me. I've updated the code to reset sys.stdout afterwards.

Comment: This is missing some error checking, but great idea

Comment: `redirect_stdout(None)` doesn't work for me when I use it with output from `argparse`. But `redirect_stdout(NonWritable())` (see about it in this topic) works!

Comment: @user10815638: I'm not sure how argparse is special. Could it be that it writes to stderr because it's an error? In that case there's redirect_stderr.

Comment: @Emil Stenström: Yes, `argparse` outputs to `sdderr` (not always) but with `contextlib.redirect_stderr(None)` it says: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'. I published a bigger example down in this topic.

Comment: @user10815638: Thanks for clarifying, and teaching me something new. Seems sys.stdout.write requires a proper write method on the redirection target stream, but print() does not. I've updated my example above to include a version that works when code is expecting a write method.

Answer (score 20):

If you're in python 3.4 or higher, there's a simple and safe solution using the standard library:

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
  print("This won't print!")
```

Comment: ```with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None)``` works as well

Comment: @ChrisCogdon Very good hint, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't work if you are using pprint library.
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'`

Comment: @Speeeddy did you get this error with python 2? You can create a class with a dummy `write` method that does nothing. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

(at least on my system) it appears that writing to os.devnull is about 5x faster than writing to a DontPrint class, i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import datetime

ITER = 10000000
def printlots(out, it, st="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"):
   temp = sys.stdout
   sys.stdout = out
   i = 0
   start_t = datetime.datetime.now()
   while i < it:
      print st
      i = i+1
   end_t = datetime.datetime.now()
   sys.stdout = temp
   print out, "\n   took", end_t - start_t, "for", it, "iterations"

class devnull():
   def write(*args):
      pass


printlots(open(os.devnull, 'wb'), ITER)
printlots(devnull(), ITER)
```

gave the following output:

```
<open file '/dev/null', mode 'wb' at 0x7f2b747044b0> 
   took 0:00:02.074853 for 10000000 iterations
<__main__.devnull instance at 0x7f2b746bae18> 
   took 0:00:09.933056 for 10000000 iterations
```

Comment: Just for the record, next time you want to time something, just use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

Answer (score 6):

If you're in a Unix environment (Linux included), you can redirect output to `/dev/null`:

```
python myprogram.py > /dev/null
```

And for Windows:

```
python myprogram.py > nul
```

Comment: Its better to have a solution which would work on all platforms.

Comment: @Guanidene, perhaps, but if he is the only person using his program, he can pretty much guarantee the environment.

Comment: `nul = myfunc()`  ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just mock it.

```
import mock

sys.stdout = mock.MagicMock()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to deal with resource-allocation nor rolling your own class, you may want to use `TextIO` from Python typing. It has all required methods stubbed for you by default.

```
import sys
from typing import TextIO

sys.stdout = TextIO()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class will work just fine (with the exception of the `write()` method name -- it needs to be called `write()`, lowercase). Just make sure you save a copy of `sys.stdout` in another variable.

If you're on a *NIX, you can do `sys.stdout = open('/dev/null')`, but this is less portable than rolling your own class.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack, redirect_stdout
import os

with ExitStack() as stack:
    if should_hide_output():
        null_stream = open(os.devnull, "w")
        stack.enter_context(null_stream)
        stack.enter_context(redirect_stdout(null_stream))
    noisy_function()
```

This uses the features in the [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/contextlib.html) module to hide the output of whatever command you are trying to run, depending on the result of `should_hide_output()`, and then restores the output behavior after that function is done running.

If you want to hide standard error output, then import `redirect_stderr` from `contextlib` and add a line saying `stack.enter_context(redirect_stderr(null_stream))`.

The main downside it that this only works in Python 3.4 and later versions.

Comment: It is easy to support [`redirect_stdout()`'s analog on earlier Python versions (e.g. using `contextlib.contextmanager`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279).

Answer (score 1):

```py
sys.stdout = None
```

It is OK for `print()` case. But it can cause an error if you call any method of sys.stdout, e.g. `sys.stdout.write()`.

There is a [note in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__stderr__):

> Under some conditions stdin, stdout and stderr as well as the original
>   values **stdin**, **stdout** and **stderr** can be None. It is usually
>   the case for Windows GUI apps that aren’t connected to a console and
>   Python apps started with pythonw.

Comment: "OK" and "Won't throw an error the moment you try to print" are very different things in this case.

Comment: You're right. You can't call any method with `sys.stdout = Null` so in some cases it can be dangerous.

Comment: In this exact case it is known to be dangerous. OP specifically addresses the error he gets from doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Supplement to [iFreilicht's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47419332/2840134) - it works for both python 2 & 3.

```py
import sys

class NonWritable:
    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class StdoutIgnore:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.stdout_saved = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = NonWritable()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        sys.stdout = self.stdout_saved

with StdoutIgnore():
    print("This won't print!")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of good answers in the flow, but here is my Python 3 answer (when sys.stdout.fileno() isn't supported anymore) :

```
import os
import sys
oldstdout = os.dup(1)
oldstderr = os.dup(2)
oldsysstdout = sys.stdout
oldsysstderr = sys.stderr

# Cancel all stdout outputs (will be lost) - optionally also cancel stderr
def cancel_stdout(stderr=False):
    sys.stdout.flush()
    devnull = open('/dev/null', 'w')
    os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), 1)
    sys.stdout = devnull
    if stderr:
        os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), 2)
        sys.stderr = devnull

# Redirect all stdout outputs to a file - optionally also redirect stderr
def reroute_stdout(filepath, stderr=False):
    sys.stdout.flush()
    file = open(filepath, 'w')
    os.dup2(file.fileno(), 1)
    sys.stdout = file
    if stderr:
        os.dup2(file.fileno(), 2)
        sys.stderr = file

# Restores stdout to default - and stderr
def restore_stdout():
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.close()
    os.dup2(oldstdout, 1)
    os.dup2(oldstderr, 2)
    sys.stdout = oldsysstdout
    sys.stderr = oldsysstderr
```

To use it:

- Cancel all stdout and stderr outputs with:

  cancel_stdout(stderr=True)
- Route all stdout (but not stderr) to a file:

  reroute_stdout('output.txt')
- To restore stdout and stderr:

  restore_stdout()

Answer (score 0):

Will add some example to the numerous answers here:

```
import argparse
import contextlib

class NonWritable:
    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my program')
parser.add_argument("-p", "--param", help="my parameter", type=str, required=True)

#with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None): # No effect as `argparse` will output to `stderr`
#with contextlib.redirect_stderr(None): # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
with contextlib.redirect_stderr(NonWritable): # this works!
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

The normal output would be:

```
>python TEST.py
usage: TEST.py [-h] -p PARAM
TEST.py: error: the following arguments are required: -p/--param
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this.  Redirect `stdout` to a string, which you subsequently ignore.  I use a context manager to save and restore the original setting for `stdout`.

```py
from io import StringIO
...
with StringIO() as out:
    with stdout_redirected(out):
        # Do your thing
```

where `stdout_redirected` is defined as:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def stdout_redirected(new_stdout):
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = new_stdout
    try:
        yield None
    finally:
        sys.stdout = save_stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, and wanted to share a recently discovered method, applicable to Python 3.8+.

#### Using `os.devnull`:

The question is how to 'send stdout to nothing'. Well, let's do just that, using `/dev/null`!

```
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f := open(os.devnull, 'w')):
    ... # code continues
    f.close()
```

The [named expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) file handle (`f`) is assigned during the call to `open`, and thus can be closed at the end of the redirection context. Thanks to the fondly named, '[walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions)'.

The key that separates this answer from others, is the ability to **close the file handle** responsibly and prevent the  `ResourceWarning` and underlying file access issues.

#### Background:

The following method, while more simple, does work in some contexts. However, this had undesired side effects which ultimately resulted in unit tests failing; which lead to the implementation shown above.

```
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    ...  # code continues
```

---

#### Imports

```
import contextlib
import os
```