# Withholding all print statements in python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to cancel print statements in a python script without deleting the print command itself? For example, let's say I have a program that looks like the following:

```
print("a")
print("b")
print("c")
...
print("z")
```

Is it possible to make it such that nothing is printed without putting everything within a function?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can.  You want to redirect `stdout`.  The linked duplicate includes an approach for doing so.

Comment: Here's [another dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735917/redirecting-stdout-to-nothing-in-python)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Should I delete my question then?

Comment: If you want.  Not like it's getting down-voted.

Comment: I guess it doesn't hurt to leave it. I appreciate the advice!

Comment: @jj172 it's useful for future visitors that may be using certain search terms to come across your post and see the linked duplicate - so best to leave it :)