# Python-Undoing stdout redirect

Tags: python

So I know from

[Redirecting stdout to "nothing" in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735917/redirecting-stdout-to-nothing-in-python)

that you can suppress print statements. But is it possible to undo that command later on, so that after a certain points, print statements will indeed be printed again?

For example, let's say I want to print "b" but not "a".

I would do:

```
import os
f = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stdout = f

print("a")

# SOME COMMAND

print("b")
```

Could someone enlighten me as to what "SOME COMMAND" would be?

Comment: use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) and don't worry about it.

Comment: You could use a context manager as shown in [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
import sys

f = open(os.devnull, 'w')
x = sys.stdout # save sys.stdout
sys.stdout = f

print("a")


sys.stdout = x # re-assign sys.stdout
print("b") # print 'b'
```

Answer (score 6):

The original `sys.stdout` is always preserved in [`sys.__stdout__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.__stdin__):

```
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

However, the documentation does note that explictly saving the original `sys.stdout` is preferred:

> It can also be used to restore the actual files to known working file
>   objects in case they have been overwritten with a broken object.
>   However, the preferred way to do this is to explicitly save the
>   previous stream before replacing it, and restore the saved object.

Answer (score 2):

starting from python 3.4 you can do this (see [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=context#contextlib.redirect_stdout))

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with redirect_stdout(None):
    # stdout suppressed
# stdout restored
```

`stdout` is suppressed within the with statement. outside the `with` context your `stdout` is restored.

and by the way: there is no need to `f = open(os.devnull, 'w')` in your original version - `sys.stdout = None` is enough as i recently learned: [why does sys.stdout = None work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757674/why-does-sys-stdout-none-work) .