# why does sys.stdout = None work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, python-internals

i can silence and restore `sys.stdout` this way:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = None
print('hello')  # does not write to stdout
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print('hello')  # writes to stdout
```

i know i'd better be using [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=redirect_stdout#contextlib.redirect_stdout) which probably does something similar but my question is: why does the above code work?

i'd have assumed python would call things like `sys.stdout.write()` so whatever i replace `sys.stdout` with should have a `write` method (like e.g. [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO)) at least.

Comment: The footnote in docs says they can be None in some conditions: Under some conditions `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` as well as the original values `__stdin__`, `__stdout__` and `__stderr__` can be None.

Comment: I think this is [the footnote](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__) @AshwiniChaudhary may be referring to.

Comment: ok, i missed the footnote. thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`print` has an explicit check for `None`.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1773)

```c
    /* sys.stdout may be None when FILE* stdout isn't connected */
    if (file == Py_None)
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
```

Comment: i was digging through the source code and had trouble finding that (should have grepped for `builtin_print`)... thanks!

Comment: Pypy is also following it as is: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/ed869ecba5203208b21f7ec6f0be86fbffa3fcb0/pypy/module/__builtin__/app_io.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#app_io.py-92

Comment: is it a documented behavior we may rely on?

Comment: @jfs: The fact that sys.stdout may be None is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__stdin__); as far as I can tell, the behavior of print when it encounters None for sys.stdout is not.