# What does it mean when sys.stdout is None

Tags: python, io, stdout

[From the docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__)

> Under some conditions stdin, stdout and stderr as well as the original values **stdin**, **stdout** and **stderr** can be None. It is usually the case for Windows GUI apps that aren’t connected to a console and Python apps started with pythonw.

- Why would a standard stream be set to `None`?
- What are the consequences of standard in/out being `None`?
- Where is the relevant code or docs explaining these consequences?

Comment: It's unclear to me what else you want to know. 1. Because it isn't connected to a console. 2. As a consequence any code that assumes that those values aren't None will likely crash (although print will be fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49757760/3001761). 3. You've quoted the docs; what code are you looking for?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the link. That  answer and comment seems to be what I want. Especially "The fact that sys.stdout may be None is documented; as far as I can tell, the behavior of print when it encounters None for sys.stdout is not"