# how to send out of ping to /dev/null

Tags: python

I wrote some code to ping the servers but I don't want the output on the screen.
But even after sending the output to `/dev/null` I am getting all the ping details on the screen.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as servers:
    for host in servers:
        response = os.system("ping -q -c 1 "+host+">/dev/null 2>&1")
        if response==0:
            print(host)
        else:
            print(host+"is dead")
```

Comment: better to use `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: ok, thank you , but why here >/dev/null 2>&1 is not working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735917/redirecting-stdout-to-nothing-in-python

Comment: you will get syntax error first on wiht open statement you havent closed the bracket

Comment: Your code works for me on Ubuntu 14.04. What platform are you on and what python version?

Comment: This is just a guess but does your particular shell require there to be some space around the ">" character? so ">/dev/null 2>&1" becomes " > /dev/null 2>&1"

Comment: no , it does not became like that. i tried both way. not sure why it is not working. very strange gor me..

Comment: @Rodney what pyrhon version are you using and how to upgrade or download python 3.3.4 in linux server? :

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import subprocess

def myping():
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as servers:
        for host in servers:
            p = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-q", "-c", "1", host], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            response = p.wait()
            if response==0:
                print(host+"is dead")
            else:
                print(host+"is up")

myping()
```

Demo

```
>>> import subprocess 
>>> host = "google.com"
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-q", "-c", "1", host], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> response = p.wait()
>>> print response
1
```

Comment: where should this be written?

Comment: still not working .. please help. i am testing 100 of servers everyday and my screen get full up...

Comment: I posted above, try it

Comment: above code does not work for me . it says host dead. even in demo output is 1 which means host is dead.

Comment: @ShankarKumar it was a silly mistake, code in if else was flipped :D

Comment: ping requests are getting timed out

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-q", "-c", "1", host], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
return_code = p.wait()
```

Avoid using `os.system`. It is deprecated, and outdated.