# How to suppress printing startup message (banner) for Ipopt?

Tags: python, startup, banner, suppress, ipopt

I am running Ipopt in a loop (from Python > Cyipopt).

Is there a way to suppress the following startup message for Ipopt?

---

This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt

---

I have already set `print_level = 0` and passing it as an Ipopt option, but I am still getting the startup message.

I also tried passing as an option from Python using `nlp.addOption('sb','yes')`, but getting the following error message:
    File "src/cyipopt.pyx", line 425, in cyipopt.problem.addOption
    TypeError: Invalid option type

(See link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-opt/TVmuXFWfeBM for the above possible solution.)

I have found another possible solution posted a while ago at https://list.coin-or.org/pipermail/ipopt/2013-September/003510.html but don't understand where and how to implement it.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37989355/8489834

Comment: You might need to do nlp.addOption(b"sb", b"yes") if using Python3.

Answer (score 1):

what works for me:

```
nlp.addOption('sb', 'yes')
nlp.addOption('print_level', 0)
```

Comment: Suggestion for improvement: You could provide some information related to rationale behind the code.