# Send screen output to /dev/null in Python

Tags: python

I am returning a variable from a function in python.

When I try to retrieve the variable in another function, it prints out the print statements of the original function for a second time.

Here is my code:

```
user_name = 'my_user'
kms_cleint = 'client_info'
aws_account = 'company-account'
def create_kms_key(user_name, kms_client):   
    print("****************************************************************")
    print("         Create KMS Key for %s                                   " % user_name)
    print("****************************************************************")
    kms_key_id = 5
    return kms_key_id

def store_secret(user_name, kms_client, secrets_client, aws_account):
    print("****************************************************************")
    print("         Store Secret for %s for AWS account: %s                " % (user_name, aws_account))
    print("****************************************************************")
    f = open(os.devnull,"w")
    kms_key_id = create_kms_key(user_name, kms_client).set_log_stream(f)
```

My output:

```
****************************************************************
         Create KMS Key for user35
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
         Store Secret for user35 for AWS account: company-account
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
         Create KMS Key for user35
****************************************************************
```

I am trying to avoid printing out the create_kms_key function output a second time.

I am getting this error when I try to redirect the output to /dev/null when I call the create_kms_key function:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'set_log_stream'
```

How can I keep the create_kms_key function from printing it's output a second time?

Comment: Looks like this may have been answered elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735917/redirecting-stdout-to-nothing-in-python

Comment: Thank you. I try the accepted solution from that exact stack overflow link and that didn't work. That is in the code above.

However I did find another solution in that same thread. That uses contextlib. I used `    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
        kms_key_id = create_kms_key(user_name, kms_client)` 

That worked. Thanks!

Comment: My fault, not reading your question carefully enough... sorry!

Comment: haha! That's ok man. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by doing this:

```
import contextlib
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
        kms_key_id = create_kms_key(user_name, kms_client)
```

That prevents the function from printing out a second time.

Answer (score 2):

The error has to do with this line:

```
create_kms_key(user_name, kms_client).set_log_stream(f)
```

The function `create_kms_key` returns an `int`, which then you immediately call `.set_log_stream(f)`, which is not a method of `int`.  Not only that, but `create_kms_key` runs completely before `.set_log_stream(f)` gets invoked.

Instead of these lines:

```
f = open(os.devnull,"w")
kms_key_id = create_kms_key(user_name, kms_client).set_log_stream(f)
```

try these instead:

```
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
    saved_stdout = sys.stdout  # save off the real stdout
    sys.stdout = devnull       # temporarily suppress stdout
    kms_key_id = create_kms_key(user_name, kms_client)
    sys.stdout = saved_stdout  # restore stdout
```

This way you'll temporarily suppress the text normally written to `sys.stdout`.  You'll have to be careful about any exceptions thrown in `create_kms_key`, as they could skip over the restoration line of code, preventing `sys.stdout` from being properly restored.

Comment: That looks like a nice solution! I will give that a try. I've already solved this with contextlib, as I mention above.  But it's good to have that as an option. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, good!  To be honest, the `contextlib` solution you found probably handles the exception issue I was talking about, so it's probably the safer solution.  (It's also a little shorter, too.)

Comment: Yup! That's what I like about it. It's harmless, succinct and works great! What's not to love?