# Python subprocess module does not return stdout on segfault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, subprocess

I'm running a C executable from Python and this executable sometimes segfaults. When it segfaults the subprocess module does not return anything in stdout or stderr.

Sample code:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['./a.out'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print 'out: "%s"' % out
print 'err: "%s"' % err
print proc.returncode
```

The source for `a.out` is:

```
int main() {
    printf("hello world\n");
    int x = 1 / 0;
}
```

The output of `./a.out` is:

```
hello world
Floating point exception
```

The output of the Python code is (in Linux, python 2.7):

```
out: ""
err: ""
-8
```

Is there a way to get the output of the executable even if it crashes?

A generic method to translate returncode to a string message, would also be nice.

Answer (score 3):

The application is almost certainly not flushing its output buffers before it encounters the segmentation fault.

By default, the C stdio library configures buffering for `stdout` so that the buffers are flushed at every end of line, but only is `stdout` is a tty. That's why you *do* see the output when you run `a.out` from the command line.

You cannot directly make the C program change this from the Python side. But what you *can* do is give it a tty to use for its `stdout`, namely a pseudo tty. The details of opening and setting up a pseudo terminal are much more complicated than setting up a regular pipe, but there are some modules that will help you: See [Pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527197/intercepting-stdout-of-a-subprocess-while-it-is-running), among others.

Answer (score 3):

Your C program is not flushing its output buffer. The easiest way around this problem is to change the output mode of STDOUT to unbuffered:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    setvbuf(stdout,_IONBF,0,0);
    printf("hello world\n");
    int x = 1 / 0;
}
```

Now your program (which I edited to fix a typo) produces the correct output:

```
$ python2.7 x.py
out: "hello world
"
err: ""
0
$
```

The return code is 0 on my Mac, confusingly, because programs that are terminated for a signal don't have a return code.

Comment: Good solution, if you control the C code and are able to add the `setvbuf` call into it and recompile. I was assuming third-party C code which it is out of the question to modify.

Comment: Well, if your third party code doesn't flush its stdout before it crashes, there isn't much you can do.