# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11 - How to fix?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, raspberry-pi, geckodriver

I want to setup https://github.com/mukulhase/WebWhatsapp-Wrapper on my Raspberry Pi Zero W. I used this (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=167292#p1246095) as "tutorial" for installing Gecko Driver. Instead of

```
curl -O {link}
```

I used

```
wget {link}
```

because

```
tar -xzvf {file}
```

didn't work for me.

At the moment when I wanted to open Firefox (you can see below in my code) it fails. I hope anybody could help me.

I tried to use another version of geckodriver but it didn't work, too.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11
```

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11
```

...implies that the [**subprocess**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) [**`exited`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html) and **Status code was: -11**

You need to download the latest matching **geckodriver** from [**Releases · mozilla/geckodriver**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

As you are on **Raspberry Pi Zero W** you need to download **`geckodriver-v0.23.0-arm7hf.tar.gz`** and save it within your system. Additionally, you need to mention the *absolute path* of the **geckodriver** binary passing the *argument* **`executable_path`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
driver.get("http://google.com/")
driver.quit()
```

### References

- [Determining if a python subprocess segmentation faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731791/determining-if-a-python-subprocess-segmentation-faults)
- [Python subprocess module does not return stdout on segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577055/python-subprocess-module-does-not-return-stdout-on-segfault)
- [Intercepting stdout of a subprocess while it is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527197/intercepting-stdout-of-a-subprocess-while-it-is-running)

Answer (score 0):

Someone found out that the RasPi Zero uses arm6hf but I used geckodriver for arm7hf.