# subprocess.call() interacting with GUI (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, subprocess

Is there any way to use `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen()` and interact with the stdin via Tkinter's `Entry` widget, and output the stdout to a `Text` widget?

Im not really sure how to approach something like this, as i am new to using the `subprocess` module.

Comment: wow haha, first time one of my questions went on without even a comment for a day ;P

Comment: There are plenty of answers on SO and elsewhere (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665566/python-tkinter-shell-to-gui) for redirecting stdout to Tkinter widgets. However, I also would like to know how to pass stdin to the subprocess from a GUI widget if anyone happens to know!

Comment: Yeah, i wanna know how to get the STDIN to work (That would be awsome! xD) but ty for the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I've got the basics of using an `Entry` as stdin to subprocess. You may have to jiggle it about for your own needs (re: output to `Text` widget).

This example calls a test script:

```
# test.py:

#!/usr/bin/env python
a = raw_input('Type something!: \n') #the '\n' flushes the prompt
print a
```

that simply requires some input (from `sys.stdin`) and prints it.

Calling this and interacting with it via a GUI is done with:

```
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess

root = Tk() 

e = Entry(root)
e.grid()

b = Button(root,text='QUIT',command=root.quit)
b.grid()

def entryreturn(event):
    proc.stdin.write(e.get()+'\n') # the '\n' is important to flush stdin
    e.delete(0,END)

# when you press Return in Entry, use this as stdin 
# and remove it
e.bind("<Return>", entryreturn)

proc = subprocess.Popen('./test.py',stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

root.mainloop()
```

Now whatever is typed into `Entry` `e` (followed by the `Return` key), is then passed via stdin to `proc`.

Hope this helps.

---

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527197/intercepting-stdout-of-a-subprocess-while-it-is-running) for ideas about stdout of subprocess question. You'll need to write a new stdout to redirect stdout to the textwidget, something like:

```
class MyStdout(object):
    def __init__(self,textwidget):
        self.textwidget = textwidget
    def write(self,txt):
        self.textwidget.insert(END,txt)

sys.stdout = MyStdout(mytextwidget)
```

but I would recommend reading other examples where people have achieved this.

Comment: replacing `sys.stdout` with Python object won't affect `subprocess`' stdout, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279). To display subprocess' stdout in a GUI widget, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32682520/4279)