# Python3 subprocess.Popen.readline is not live

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, synchronization, subprocess

I try to run this script:

```
file = open("console-output.txt", "w")
task = subprocess.Popen(sys.executable + " \"main.py\"", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(task.stdout.readline, ''):
  print("Got data")
  file.write(line)
  file.flush()
file.close()
```

It works fine and prints the program output to the console-output.txt file. However it outputs every text at once at the end of the program. I would like to have a live output to my file so that I can see the output of long-running programs. Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug? I am on Ubuntu 17.10 with Python 3.6.3 64Bit.

It seems to me like `task.stdout.readline` is blocking till the program is completely finished.

Comment: Please outline what is different from my code? This is not a duplicate since IMHO my code should work.

Comment: Are you sure that the `main.py` script is actually using line-buffered output, or is flushing its output on every line? If not, you'll have to wait for a block to fill up or for the subprocess to exit before the output becomes available to read in the parent process.

Comment: As an aside: There is absolutely no point (and a non-trivial security risk) in using a string argument and `shell=True` here. Just use `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "main.py"], ..)` and there's no need for a shell process at all.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but closely related: http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe

Comment: Well, I will have to check that. Thanks in advance...

Comment: why not adding `print(line)` in your loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercepting stdout of a subprocess while it is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527197/intercepting-stdout-of-a-subprocess-while-it-is-running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more research using different search terms, I found out that C (and therefore many interpreters and programs) detects whether the program output is a console or a pipe. It buffers every output, as soon as the buffer has enough empty space or is not flushed, if in pipe mode. To force an unbuffered behaviour, you just need to pass `-u` to the target python interpreter. If not using Python, you may want to try the `stdbuf` command pre-installed on almost all common linux platforms, available via the `coreutils` package in Mac OS X (you have to call `gstdbuf` instead of `stdbuf` ). After a lot of research, I found out that the only equivalent for stdbuf on linux could be the stdbuf.exe found in the `git-scm` for windows. However I did not test it yet.